# “Ha-Melekh Hakodosh” after Yom Kippur?

Tags: halacha, shemoneh-esrei, yom-kippur

What will be the situation if instead of saying “Ho-Ail Hakodosh” after Yom Kippur, I say “Ha-Melekh  Hakodosh”?

Do we say that “Ha-Melekh  Hakodosh” is greater than “Ho-Ail Hakodosh” and it's ok or that it's too strong for that time of year?